# How can I route requests to sub-directories using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm coming from a PHP MVC background and I'm starting to use AngularJS. In PHP I would do something like this to direct the user to different parts of a website: grab the url, split it up, then send the user to the requested page. For example, if the user entered www.mysite.com/info/product/1, then PHP would split up this url and say "okay, use the 'info' controller." Then, the 'info' controller would say "okay, use the product controller." This controller would do what it does, and then send the user to the requested url.

In angular I'm trying to figure out the equivalent to this. I've seen things like this:

```
angular.module('phonecat', []).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',   controller: PhoneListCtrl}).
  when('/phones/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: PhoneDetailCtrl}).
  otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});
}]);
```

Does this mean that I have to enter in every possible url this way? In other words, do I have to duplicate the above code for any url that is a sub link of www.mysite.com/phones/. Like this:

```
....
when('/phones',...).
when('/phones/:phoneId',...).
...
```

and then do the same for some other directory (e.g., www.mysite.com/computers/...).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right path (pun intended).

In the route provider you define what view and controller will be used for a given URL ($location) essentially.  Along with the path itself you can include parameters as you show with phoneId.  Keep in mind these aren't paths on the server, these are simply URLs being used by the angular application to keep track of it's history and navigate for "deep linking" to show the appropriate view when a link is copied.

If you're doing some sort of RESTful interface where the PHP has some "directory structure" or URL that implies the data model that is a separate issue.  You would handle that by using the $resource in AngularJS I believe though I'm not familiar with actually implementing this.  So far I've used $http in a service I define to handle my calls to the server and am just manually setting up what files are called, but for large complex projects a REST interface is probably a good idea so as to avoid all the manual work and potential errors.

Comment: Thanks! You helped clarify several things for me. I'm new to AngularJS, but I'm quite sure it is the future of front-end development.

Comment: @NancyCollier No problem, I've been stumbling my way through it all after watching tons of videos, so I have some abstract idea of how everything should work I think, but still learning to put it all into practice correctly.